# can anyone help me in generating a automated script to create a database

Tags: sql-server, automation

I need help in generating a automated script for database where I can give parameters for database name, size etc.

I need automated script to create a database where in I can give parameters for instance name, database name, size of the database.

So far I have created a powershell script to create databases but I want to bypass that create a stored procedure where I can insert parameters.

My powershell script looks like this

```
#Import SQL Server Module called SQLPS
Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking

#Your SQL Server Instance Name
$Inst = "YourInstanceName"
$Srvr = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList $Inst

#database PSDB with default settings
#by assuming that this database does not yet exist in current instance
$DBName = "databasename"
$db = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($Srvr, $DBName)
$db.Create()
```

Comment: What have you tried so fat? What do you want to create precisely and why? If you don't give much details your question will most likely be tagged as too broad or unclear what you are asking or off topic and will be closed. [How do I ask a good question?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: eidted the question

Comment: The procedure will be stored on one instance and you will connect to this instance. You can then execute it from this instance and create a DB on this same instance only. If you want to create DB on any instance, Powershell is probably a better option.

Comment: it will be part of maintenance database which will be created by default when we build servers so creating a stored procedure where I can input parameters like database name, size of the database I think that would do.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is just to script out a database and then parameterize it the way you want.  Use that to dump into a query and then just pass in the query.  Here is a very simple example...

**Powershell Method**

```
[string]$sqlInstance
[string]$dbName
[string]$dbInitialSize
[string]$dbMaxSize
[string]$dbGrowthSize
[string]$logInitialSize
[string]$logMaxSize
[stinrg]$logGrowthSize


$sqlQuery=
"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N`'$dbName`')
BEGIN
CREATE DATABASE [$dbName] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N`'$dbName`', FILENAME = N`'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQL2K8R2\MSSQL\DATA\$dbName.mdf`' , SIZE = $dbInitialSize , MAXSIZE = $dbMaxSize, FILEGROWTH = $dbFileGrowth )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N`'$dbName`', FILENAME = N`'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQL2K8R2\MSSQL\DATA\$dbName`_log.ldf`' , SIZE = $logInitialSize , MAXSIZE = $logMaxSize , FILEGROWTH = $logFileGrowth)
 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
END"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $sqlQuery -ServerInstance $sqlInstance
```

**Stored Procedure Method**

```
USE master
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('usp_CreateMaintenanceDB','P') IS NULL
    EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE PROC dbo.usp_CreateMaintenanceDB AS SELECT ''STUB'' STUB'
GO

ALTER PROC dbo.usp_CreateMaintenanceDB
(
      @dbName VARCHAR(255)
    , @mdfPath VARCHAR(259)
    , @logPath VARCHAR(259)
    , @dbInitialSize VARCHAR(25)
    , @dbMaxSize VARCHAR(25)
    , @dbGrowthSize VARCHAR(25)
    , @logInitialSize VARCHAR(25)
    , @logMaxSize VARCHAR(25)
    , @logGrowthSize VARCHAR(25)
)
AS

DECLARE @sqlCmd NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sqlCmd=N'
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'''+@dbName+''')
BEGIN
CREATE DATABASE ['+@dbName+'] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'''+@dbName+''', FILENAME = N'''+@mdfPath+@dbName+'.mdf'' , SIZE = '+@dbInitialSize+' , MAXSIZE = '+@dbMaxSize+', FILEGROWTH = '+@dbGrowthSize+' )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'''+@dbName+'_log'', FILENAME = N'''+@logPath+@dbName+'_log.ldf'' , SIZE = '+@logInitialSize+' , MAXSIZE = '+@logMaxSize+', FILEGROWTH = '+@logGrowthSize+' )
 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
END'

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCmd
```

**SAMPLE CALL**

```
exec dbo.usp_CreateMaintenanceDB
      @dbName        = 'TEST2'
    , @mdfPath       = 'c:\mssqlserver\sqlversion\data\'
    , @logPath       = 'c:\mssqlserver\sqlversion\log\'
    , @dbInitialSize = '2048MB'
    , @dbMaxSize     = 'UNLIMITED'
    , @dbGrowthSize  = '1024KB'
    , @logInitialSize= '512KB'
    , @logMaxSize    = 'UNLIMITED'
    , @logGrowthSize = '512KB'
```

Comment: I was thinking of creating a stored procedure instead of having a powershell script.

Comment: Use the same approach only you are going to use dynamic SQL and the sp_executesql stored proceudure to execute the dynamic SQL.  Powershell would be much easier for this type of automation, IMHO.

Comment: Added a stored procedure example, written and tested with 2008R2.  Should be fine in more current versions.  Again, this is just an example.  There are a lot of options you could script out and get much more fancy than this.

Comment: Msg 8146, Level 16, State 2, Procedure usp_CreateMaintenanceDB, Line 0
Procedure usp_CreateMaintenanceDB has no parameters and arguments were supplied.
I get the above error when I tried to test it on my box. I am new to SQL server please let me know if my questions are naive.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't create the SP correctly, but hard to troubleshoot from that one line.  I ran that exact code on my box without issue. Check object explorer and make sure the sp was created correctly.  Make sure you didn't miss any punctuation anywhere in either execution or sp call

Comment: when I delete the SP and recreate again it gives me error message of the stored procedure already exists.

Comment: The code above is designed to be rerun over and over again with the same exact results. The IF OBJECT_ID checks to see if it exists and creates if it doesn't.  Then it's just an ALTER command.  The only way it tries to create is if it doesn't already exist.   I'm not sure what you are doing, but you don't appear to be running the code provided.